# Oracle stored procedure java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 2012 (REF_CURSOR)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, sys-refcursor, ref-cursor

Oracle 11g, Java 8, ojdbc8/ojdbc7

stored procedure with OUT REF_CURSOR, e.g.,

```
create or replace procedure foo(employeeId IN number, c OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
    open c for select * from Employee where id = employeeId;
END;
```

From sqlplus, it works fine.

JDBC call the procedure:

```
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{call foo(?,?)}");
statement.setObject(1, 100);
statement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.REF_CURSOR);  // ERROR here
statement.execute();
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 2012
```

type 2012 is Types.REF_CURSOR.

Tried both ojdbc7 and ojdbc8 with oracle 11g, same error.
Oracle 11g supports REFCURSOR. java 8 defines Types.REF_CURSOR. Which oracle jdbc driver should I use for 11g?

Comment: hey mate. Did you solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

i used this code in my project and it's work very well

```
@Override
public ResultSet getCorrespondenceDetail(Long id)  {
    String sql="{call dbpk_person_correspondence.get_report_detail(?,?   )}";
    Connection conn = JDBCUtility.getConnection();
    ResultSet result = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt;
    try {
        cstmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    cstmt.setLong(2,id);
    cstmt.execute();
    result = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

project dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried ojdbc6 11.2.0.3, got error java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method oracle/jdbc/driver/OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.closeOnCompletion()V is abstract
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.closeOnCompletion(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java)

Comment: which JDBC type is mapped to oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR? It is better to use JDBC type instead of vender-specific type.

Comment: see this  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm

Comment: Oracle type REF_CURSOR is mapped to JDBC type java.sql.ResultSet. The java.sql.Types.REF_CURSOR is designed for this purpose. But it is invalid column type for oracle db. CallableStatement.registerOutParameter takes a parameter value defined in java.sql.Types, not java type.

Answer (score 1):

Using spring jdbc I got the same eror but I solved using OracleTypes.CURSOR like this.

```
  SimpleJdbcCall jdbc=new SimpleJdbcCall(this.dataSource)
            .withSchemaName("DELIVERY")
            .withCatalogName("PKG_APISTOCK")
            .withProcedureName("SP_S_STOCK_PRODUCTO")
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlParameter("P_COD_LOCAL", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("P_COD_PRODUCTO", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("P_CIA", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlOutParameter("C_STOCK", OracleTypes.CURSOR,new StockMapper()));
```

Answer (score 0):

***Remove*** all your classpath entries ( perhaps *ojdbc7.jar* or *classesXX.jar* etc. ) *other* than you use ***from your classpath***.

> The `class path` is the path that the Java runtime environment searches
>   for classes and other resource files. The class search path (more
>   commonly known by the shorter name, "class path") can be set using
>   either the `-classpath` option when calling a JDK tool (the preferred
>   method) or by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. The
>   -classpath option is preferred because you can set it individually for each application without affecting other applications and without
>   other applications modifying its value.
>
> `C:> sdkTool -classpath classpath1;classpath2...`
>
> -or-
>
> `C:> set CLASSPATH=classpath1;classpath2...`
>
> where:
>
> **sdkTool** A command-line tool, such as java, javac, javadoc, or apt. For
>   a listing, see JDK Tools. **classpath1;classpath2** Class paths to the
>   .jar, .zip or .class files. Each classpath should end with a filename
>   or directory depending on what you are setting the class path to: For
>   a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends
>   with the name of the .zip or .jar file. For .class files in an unnamed
>   package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the
>   .class files. For .class files in a named package, the class path ends
>   with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package
>   in the full package name). Multiple path entries are separated by
>   semi-colons. With the set command, it's important to omit spaces from
>   around the equals sign (=).
>
> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH
>   variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search
>   path, you must include "." in the new settings.
>
> Classpath entries that are neither directories nor archives (`.zip` or
>   `.jar` files) nor * are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

For Scala add below dependency to your build.sbt file.

`libraryDependencies += "com.oracle.ojdbc" % "ojdbc8" % "19.3.0.0"`

Then you can call to your stored procedure.

```
val callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call foo(?)}")
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR)
callableStatement.execute()
```